# SharePoint Navigation Edit Links is not visible

Tags: permissions, navigation, term-store

I created top navigation using Metadata term set.
I have full control on this site.
Why I can not see the link "Edit links" for quick edit navigation terms?
What permission is responsible for adding this link to the page?

If I choose "Structural Navigation" in Navigation Settings, I see "EDIT LINKS", but with "Managed Navigation" it does not work.

The main problem is that our main site uses the same navigation, but there "Edit links" is visible for all users, even with viewing rights. Now I hid this link with css, but some users can open develop console and disable my css. I have to find a way to prevent it.

Comment: Maybe it can help someone, but this is not the solution to the whole problem.
I added the following script to the master-page:
     

(function fixEditLink() {
    var a = document.getElementById("DeltaTopNavigation").getElementsByClassName("ms-listMenu-editLink");
    if (a.length == 1) {
        a[0].parentNode.removeChild(a[0]);
    }
})()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution!

1. Open master-page (How to check master-page filename: `{site url}/_api/web?$select=CustomMasterUrl,MasterUrl`)
2. Find:

   ```
                       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                       <SharePoint:AspMenu
                           ID="TopNavigationMenu"
                           Runat="server"
                           EnableViewState="false"
                           DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                           AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                           UseSimpleRendering="true"
                           UseSeparateCss="false"
                           Orientation="Horizontal"
                           StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                           AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                           MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                           SkipLinkText="" />
                   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   ```
3. Add Editable="false" for hidding Edit Links or Editable="true" for showing

   ```
                       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                       <SharePoint:AspMenu
                           ID="TopNavigationMenu"
                           Runat="server"
                           EnableViewState="false"
                           Editable="false"
                           DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                           AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                           UseSimpleRendering="true"
                           UseSeparateCss="false"
                           Orientation="Horizontal"
                           StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                           AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                           MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                           SkipLinkText="" />
                   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
   ```

Don't forget to publish your master-page!
So, now you can add/remove "Edit Links" without css(css!)

Answer (score 1):

Edit links has lot of rules. please check below blog for more info.
http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/09/edit-links-missing-in-sharepoint-2013-navigation.html

Comment: Thank you! I have read many similar articles, but I use "Managed Navigation" with terms( But now I have a real solution =)